# In game FPS limiter vs. RTS FPS limiter?

Tags: hardware

I'm currently using an in game frame limiter to cap fps, so my computer doesn't die. However, the highest limit for that is 60fps. I'd like to cap the fps at 100-144, ideally.

It seems that RTSS lets you do this, but does that also have the effect of lowering stress on the cpu / gpu? I've heard people say that the RTSS frame limiter doesn't actually limit how many frames are sent to the GPU, only how many are rendered.

Comment: This is highly game dependent. You can't magically make frames where there are none, so if a game is meant to play at 60, you can have unintended consequences by uncapping frames. IE fallout games, where physics is tied to FPS, and can cause major game problems by uncapping.

Also, if you don't want your PC to die, 100-144 seems like a stressful number for your hardware based on your description.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. In my case I am playing Guild Wars 2, which tends to run between 150-200fps when I don't set a cap.